# how can i go about this task,regards

Tags: html, css

create a DIV with a CSS class of menu

The .menu DIV should contain 4 DIV elements having a class of item

Each .item DIV should have an IMAGE displaying a placeholder from https://placeholder.com/ and a PARAGRAPH with class of mdc-typography--headline6

I've tried this code and  I've commented out the placeholders as im not being allowed to post pictures. gonna be so grateful

```
<div class="item">

            <!--<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />-->

      <p1 class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p1>
    </div>

    <div class="item">

      <!--  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150"/> --->

      <p1 class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p1>
    </div>

    <div class="item">

        <!--<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150"/>--->

      <p1 class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p1>
    </div>

    <div class="item">

        <!--<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150"/>--->

      <p1 class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi , Welcome to SO :) . Please have a look at the **Asking** section here https://stackoverflow.com/help, will help you in receiving assistance faster !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. It's `<p>` not `<p1>`

```
<div class="menu">
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/> 
      <p class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/> 
      <p class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/> 
      <p class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p>
   </div>

   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/> 
      <p class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much mr chuks, but i tried such a code and still was rejected i request you to cross examine the question my be there is a way it has to be twisted_regards

Answer (score 0):

i think you have problem in write paragraph. you must write paragraph like `<p>` and closed by `</p>`.When you write a header , you need write like that `<h1>` and close by `</h1>`.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="item">

    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150"/> 

  <p >mdc-typograpy--headline6</p>
</div>

<div class="item">

   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150" > 
   <p>mdc-typograpy--headline6</p>
</div>

<div class="item">

    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150"/>

  <p >mdc-typograpy--headline6</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: <div class="item">
  <p1 class="mdc-typograpy--headline6"></p1> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
    </div>     the paragraph has no class